# Can oozie monitor a directory for new files in hdfs directory?

Tags: hadoop, hive, oozie, oozie-coordinator

I need to perform the following workflow on my hadoop cluster.

- New files are added into an hdfs directory, /export/ (multiple times a day)
- Files are in two formats: *_A.csv and *_B.csv
- Copy all *_A.csv into /hive/dumptable_a/
- Copy all *_B.csv into /hive/dumptable_b/
- Run hive insert query to load partitioned table A from dumptable_a
- Run hive insert query to load partitioned table B from dumptable_b
- Delete data from /hive/dumptable_a/ and /hive/dumptable_b/

Can oozie be set up to monitor /export/ for new files, and kick off the workflow?
If oozie cannot do this, or if it is not the right tool, what is the best alternative?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Oozie file based coordinator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27863577/oozie-file-based-coordinator)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as Rahul mentioned, please look at [Oozie file based coordinator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27863577/oozie-file-based-coordinator), where you can find an example on how to use the `<datasets>` and `<input-events>` elements.

Or you can look at an example in oozie documentation [here](https://oozie.apache.org/docs/3.1.3-incubating/CoordinatorFunctionalSpec.html#a6.2._Synchronous_Coordinator_Application_Example)